# How do the denials work in this case?

Tags: meaning

個人的にはお姫様キャラっぽくて、こういうのも悪くない気もしないでもないかな

でもない is like "denying explicitly one thing and also denying explicitly the other thing as well"

So でもない is supposed to deny the previous 2 ない's which would mean the sentence is in an affirmative state ?